# Audience is unable to play any videos

Tags: release-loki, videos, audience

So, I was playing around yesterday, and decided to uninstall lightdm and make an xinitrc file to start from the terminal at boot, as I like to do.
Well, after doing so, I am unable to play any videos in audience, or Videos, as it is called in the icon.
I did reinstall lightdm, but I fear I may have futzed up the session too much, so this happens:

```
[ERROR 14:08:17.236311] Inhibitor.vala:62: Could not inhibit screen: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver was not provided by any .service files
```

I would like very much to not have to install another video program, so just what the hell have I done?
I would very much appreciate any help anybody could provide to me for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by doing the following, as it needed some packages from elementary-desktop:

```
sudo apt install elementary-desktop --reinstall
```

And now it works just fine.

Comment: Can you please mark this as answered? Thanks!